# CRM Javascript How to Disable Fields on the Form Header

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We're on CRM 2016 and I have a requirement to disable all fields on the Contact form when a certain condition is met. This is the code that I use

```
var attributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
for (var i in attributes) {
    var myattribute = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(attributes[i].getName());
    var myname = myattribute.getName();
    if (Xrm.Page.getControl(myname) != null) {
        //alert(myname);
        Xrm.Page.getControl(myname).setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly except for some reason I cannot ever get to the fields on the header. Somehow getControl always returns null for the header fields. All fields on the header are not locked, but the footer itself is locked by default and I'm unable to unlock it.

Is it possible to disable header fields in CRM forms? Do I need to find a way to unlock the header on the form? I tried disabling the field itself with below code but no luck.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("mycustomfield").setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

I have to add "header_" into my field names in order to make it work

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("header_mycustomfield").setDisabled(true);
```

Comment: In D365 (don't know about earlier versions), header controls are loaded after the rest of the form. So if you are calling this in your on-load then you may need to test that the control exists before disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Like answered in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450494/7920473), you can disable all the controls in header in single shot without hard coding the names.

To optimize your code in question for disabling form controls entirely, use this:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control) {
            if (control.setDisabled) {
                control.setDisabled(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That was actually also me asking that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Tested On CRM v8.2

// lock a header control
Xrm.Page.getControl("header_statuscode").setDisabled(true);

// this won't work if statusreason is hosted in the header section
Xrm.Page.getControl("statuscode").setDisabled(true);

// lock all controls on form, including header controls
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control) {
    if (control.setDisabled) {
        control.setDisabled(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Using formContext you can also disable it.

```
 if (formContext.getControl("accountid").getAttribute()!= null)  
     formContext.getControl("accountid").setDisabled(true);
```