# How to identify Header Section in CRM Form?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is there a way to tell if the section is a header in CRM Form?

We're on Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 and I have a requirement to disable all fields on the Contact form when a certain condition is met. I'm using the code below and so far the code is working.

```
var attributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
for (var i in attributes) {
  var myattribute = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(attributes[i].getName());
  var myname = myattribute.getName();
  if (Xrm.Page.getControl(myname) != null) {
    //alert(myname);
    Xrm.Page.getControl(myname).setDisabled(true);
  }
}
```

However the reason I ask, special for header fields, you need to put `header_` before the field name in order to get to the header fields. For example `header_name`. Since our CRM Manager likes to put different fields on the header, it'd be nice to automatically disable the header fields instead of manually change it.

Is there a way to tell if the section is a header in CRM Form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically every field in the form has to be in a `section` except `header`. So this is helpful in this case as we have to identify the fields in `header` & disable it.

I have used `forEach` iterator to check each control and if that control does not have a Parent which is a `section` - then its a control in `header`, so disable the control.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control) {
            if(!control.getParent()){
              control.setDisabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Reference: [getParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg334266(v=crm.8)?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#getparent)